# Error about CASCADE in Sql - Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I posted this problem yesterday and didn't get answer.
I attach here sample of my problem. I want to create this DB:

```
CREATE DATABASE [TRYShemen];
GO 
USE [TRYShemen]
GO
CREATE TABLE Persons( 
ID VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY, 
FullName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);  



CREATE TABLE Class( 
ClassNum VARCHAR(30) PRIMARY KEY,
Teacher VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,

constraint Class_FK foreign key (Teacher) references  Persons (ID) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE,

); 

CREATE TABLE Students(
 StudentID VARCHAR(50) ,
 ClassNum VARCHAR(30) 

 constraint Students_PK PRIMARY KEY (StudentID, ClassNum),

constraint Students_FK foreign key (StudentID) references  Persons(ID) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE , 
 constraint Students_FK1 foreign key (ClassNum) references  Class(ClassNum)  ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE
 );
```

and I get an error:

```
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'Students_FK1' on table 'Students' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
```

I know that if i change the 'Students_FK1' to ON CASCADE NO ACTION, it will work, but it's not my target. I want that if the id of 'Person' will update , it will update in the Students table too.

how can I solve it?

Thank You!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what can you do about it?

Consider this structure as an alternative.

table-Persons
table-Students
table-Teachers
table-Classes
table-Classes_to_Teachers
table-Classes_to_Students

Then you can have Cascading references for
Persons-->Students  &  Students-->Classes_to_Students
Persons-->Teachers  &  Teachers-->Classes_to_Teachers

When you access your data, you will have more joins to get all the data for one class.
But the constraints should work out.

Comment: Thanks, @outisnihil.  Indeed.  And if you don't want that, user2097810, of course you can have a unique constraint on both id columns in such a Classes_to_Teachers table, as you clearly know how to do.

Comment: Actually, even more concise would be to add a "Type" to the person table...Then you wouldn't need a separate "Teachers" and "Students" table, and also only one association table, "Classes_to_People".

Answer (score 2):

Note that it says "may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths." If you follow a delete action through your ER diagram, you'll probably find that the delete action cascades to the same table via multiple routes.

In this case, imagine that the same person is both the teacher and the student in a class. Yes, I know, that's a logic error, but if that condition were true, then an update to that person would cascade to the students table via two routes.

Comment: Indeed.  And you can see the db is happy if you comment out one of the two constraints to Person.

Comment: Ok I understand, but in my case it's can't be possible that Person will be Teacher and Student. There is a way to change the tables that help to solve it?
Thank you!

Comment: You'll probably have to replace the foreign key constraints with custom triggers to manage that.

Comment: Alternatively, you can redesign the database as indicated by @MikeM in his answer.